# Need to relogin if i want to retrieve data

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

When i login into my app, it works fine and retrieve data from firebase. But when i close the app and open it later the app don't retrieve it. I need to relogin to get that functioning again. Please help.

Comment: Are you setting an `onAuthStateChanged` listener when the app is relaunched to detect when the user state is determined?

Comment: No can you assist me. How to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to `onAuthStateChanged` listener to detect when the user is ready:

```
authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
              // User signed in.
            } else {
              // User signed out.
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Where i should add this.

Comment: It is not null, I put a Toast in it but even then it is not retrieving data from firebase. Everything is working fine except data retrieval. Please help.